# My App stop responding after inserting that line myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am building my app by reusing code, I have done everything correctly but unintentionally put some error which I can't trace. I want to run RecyclerView after clicking on button showed on front page but OnClick app stop working. Most of the time I face same or related problems. I am attaching the recylerViewAdapter file and MainActivity file named as fabonacci because there is another main activity.

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.sg_dev003.twobuttons;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.List;


public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context mContext ;
private List<Fibonacci> mData ;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Fibonacci> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.cardview_item_fibonacci,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.img_fibonacci_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Fibonacci_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
            // start the activity
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mData.size(); }

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    ImageView img_fibonacci_thumbnail;
    CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        img_fibonacci_thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fibonacci_img_id);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id);
    }
}

}
```

Here is my logcat error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.sg_dev003.twobuttons, PID: 21721
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060072
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                      at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
                      at com.example.sg_dev003.twobuttons.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:42)
                      at com.example.sg_dev003.twobuttons.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:18)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1468)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.j
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21721 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Post your Fibonacci class

Answer (score 0):

I was calling `PNG` images from ...\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24

When I put my `PNG` images into ...\app\src\main\res\drawable and I call it,
My problem solved. May it will help for others